# Flex items responsive issues

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind and I made this div:
[image]

The problem is that it looks like this when I shrink it down:
[image]

**With white-space: nowrap it goes out of the div.**
[image]

**I am not able to fix this issue. However, I have made it go into columns when it goes below md screen however not sure how I can stop it from making another line when resolution changes.**

**Code:**

```
<div className='bg-gray-1000 rounded shadow border border-opacity-50 text-white flex flex-col lg:flex-row w-7/12 mx-auto justify-between p-2 mb-2 items-center md:space-x-16 whitespace-nowrap'>

            <div className='bg-primary rounded w-14 h-14 flex items-center'>
                <img src={props.logo}/>
            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-col flex-grow'>
                <div>{props.title}</div>
                <div className='flex'>
                    <div><img className='w-6 mt-1' src={props.flag}/></div>
                    <div><FaInfoCircle className='inline ml-2 text-xl'/></div>
                    <div><button className={`ml-2 rounded px-4 py-0 text-sm uppercase bg-${props.color}-600`} disabled>{props.mode}</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                <div><FaCalendar className='inline mr-2 text-xl'/> {props.date}</div>
                <div className='mt-1'><FaClock className='inline mr-2 text-xl'/> {props.time}</div>
            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                <div> <FaUsers className='inline mr-2 text-xl'/> {props.vs}</div>
                <div className='mt-1'><FaUsers className='inline mr-2 text-xl'/> {props.slots} Slots</div>
            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-col md:pr-4'>
                <div><AiFillDollarCircle color='green' className='inline mr-2 text-xl'/></div>
                <div className='mt-1'><AiFillTrophy className='inline mr-2 text-xl md:text-2xl'/> {props.prize}</div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: have you tried `white-space: nowrap`?

Comment: Yes @fevid, editing the post.

Comment: they cannot fit in smaller screen without overflowing out of your div, you should either, use smaller font-size in smaller screens or reduce the gap between columns.

Comment: @fevid the thing is all the screenshots are of lg: viewport. I have made it go into column mode once it goes to md or smaller. Will try changing the font-size and reducing the gap. But is there any better solution?

Comment: Maybe the right side of the component (date, time, prize) should go below the logo and the event name when the screen width shrinks?

Comment: @Unigazer I wanted to keep it in a row for screens above md. Below md, it goes below them automatically.

Comment: You may change `w-7/12` class to something like `w-full max-w-5xl` or `w-full lg:w-7/12` as your parent doesn't have enough space. Also `flex-wrap` is the option but it is requires additional design (where to put date, slots etc)

Answer (score 1):

the best solution for you **if** you don't want to make the fonts smaller, IMO would be: adding a wrapper on three columns at the right and making it a `flex` with `justify-content: space-between`.

It will adjust the gaps according the space left for use.

seems your title at the left content is dynamic and it can get really long, try limiting text width and using `text-overflow: ellipsis` on it. otherwise you cannot fit long text beside other content.

Comment: Did not gave the expected results, it's still going out of the div.

Comment: how are the gaps adjusted in your codes? is there margin or something that makes the gap between? if you have any margin between those columns remove the mand try again.

Comment: your solution kinda improved a bit but there's still a problem: https://i.imgur.com/8g8w9RW.png

Comment: @AviThour, is the second one the new result? what is the problem? parent not taking the full width?

Comment: both of these are the new results. The problem is it's still going out of the div.

Comment: add `width: 100%` on your parent div, then it should take the full width of browser, I'll update my answer with one more tip

Comment: I wanted the div to use the same width as of my navbar. Check: https://i.imgur.com/7M9jQMu.png - Can't really use width: 100%.

Comment: add `max-width` same as your navbar below `width: 100%`

Comment: thanks for helping me however there is no way I can fix this solution. I have tried every method available on the internet. Not sure if I can select your's as an answer however gave an upvote. Thanks for the help bud.